# Closing Navigation onClick of any area of the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown navigation which opens onClick.

What I want to happen is, that once the ul is open, I want it to close whenever the user goes to open any of the other dropdowns or clicks anywhere away from the dropdown.

At the moment, You have to specifically click the parent li to close the dropdown.

See demo

http://jsbin.com/icotef#

B

Comment: i quess you are searching for http://api.jquery.com/focusout/ or http://api.jquery.com/blur/

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like

```
$('body').click(function(){
  //if you didn't click on a descendant of the nav
  if($(this).closest('nav').length === 0){
      //close the menus
      $('.primaryNav li ul').hide();
  }
});
```